# Why return is not recommend in Scala?

Tags: scala

When I try to use `return` in Scala, you will be prompted when compiling, like:

```
The last statement in a method is automatically returned, use of the return keyword is redundant.
```

Why is `return` not recommended in Scala?
Can we really avoid using `return`?

Comment: https://blog.knoldus.com/scala-best-practices-say-no-to-return/

Comment: Have a look at what an expression mean in Scala. It might help you to understand a bit about why we do not need explicit return

Comment: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the error it says that `return` is redundant. You can just delete it and the code will work fine because, as it says, the last statement in a method is the result.

There are uses for `return` in Scala, but only in rare cases for a specific class of algorithm.